# Open source+free+webbased pdf viewer

Tags: php, pdf

I am looking for a PDF viewer which must have the following features

1. Open source
2. Free
3. Web Based
4. PHP/MySQL web-application supportive.
5. caching facility

I have already seen flexpaper, do-pdf, sumatra pdf and many others but those doesn't fulfill my above criteria

Comment: What's wrong with Adobe Reader?

Comment: @peter it has none of the requirement asked

now why do you need a web based pdf reader just link to the pdf wouldn't be sufficient for your need? on most configuration it's gonna open inside the web browser and it is much more convenient to the users

Comment: what more could you possibly want that Adobe Reader, Sumatra PDF, DoPDF, BullPDF cannot offer you??

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with Adobe Reader.

Comment: what do you mean by 4, as I think it is probably your main point...

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to show your PDF's stored on your file system without using the user's default PDF viewer? Just open it with a php viewer class (e.g. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6464-PHP-Alter-a-PDF-document-to-make-it-print-when-opened.html). It complies with 1,2,3 and 4. No.5 is up to your programming.

Comment: The class you link to is not a PHP viewer: `This class can be  used to alter a PDF document to make it print when opened.` *Is* there such a class? If there is, I'd be interested in a link.

Comment: I want to implement in my own webapplication............the viewer must have the open source facility ........I have to customize as per my webapplication's requirement

Comment: @Pekka: Mmmm. My bad. @Progyaparamita: You'd consider a iframe with and embedded (e.g.) Adobe Reader?

Comment: it's not what @Progyaparamita is asking for. That said, it could be that what the OP is asking for simply is not possible. I'm not aware of any Open Source tool that can do this.